# Blocking underling content scrolling by applying overflow: hidden to body. Why not?

Tags: css

the problem is an old one, and the solution is old too:

- To block underling body/document scroll while a fixed overlay is visible;
- Do this by applying `overflow: hidden` to the body;

Many threads have been written around this issue, but cannot find a real answer, because I cannot replicate reported issues.

The `overflow:hidden` body is not considered a good solution because people say it will scroll the page to top. But this doesn't happen to me:

https://jsfiddle.net/stratboy/cjsL2qhq/13/

I also built a real website some time ago with this technique applied, and never had bugs reports by my client or users.

So, why shouldn't I use this thing? Are there any other good reasons?

There is an article (probably one of the many) that suggests another solution, but that doesn't work if you want fixed header, since scrollbars will be under the header in safari and explorer. The simple solution above is going to work instead.

http://luxiyalu.com/how-to-prevent-body-from-scrolling/

So I was curious: am I missing something? Why mine is going to work properly? Is there any hidden pitfall?

Comment: Please include your [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @TylerH Actually, it is attached inside the fiddle. Please take back your comment.

Comment: @K.Rohde No, code must be included in the question itself per the site rules. This is why including links to JSFiddle and such give you a red banner when you don't have any code in your question. Please read the [help].

Comment: @TylerH I see. I thought you meant code being included in any kind. My apologies.

Comment: @TylerH: I understand, but there are 2 or 3 things. First, the main and very relevant code is included: body > overflow:hidden. That's the thing this question is all about, really. Second, is there a way to use sass on the Stackoverflow fiddler? Otherwise, jsfiddle is just superior and I don't have too much time to write plain css in 2017. ;) And, once upon a time stackoverflow asked for fiddles because people didn't include them. Now I'm including fiddles, and stackoverlow doesn't want fiddles anymore. Than,  it should provide a fully functional fiddler, I guess :) I will use, I promise.

Comment: @Stratboy Seeing as how Sass *compiles* to CSS before it can be used on a website, and converting is usually just a single mouse click, that argument doesn't hold up, especially when phrased in a more plain way, e.g. "I'm being lazy".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite subtle and this might only be little of what could probably go wrong:

While researching, I found [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html) about the html and body overflow. There, inside the part "Mommy, Where Do Scrollbars Come From?", the following image is shown:

[image]

What this implies is, that the `body` itself is not by default as big as the `html`, instead the `body` should even expand to enclose whatever content you have. However, this would mean that an `overflow: hidden` on the `body` should in fact have no effect at all.

But as you have experienced, this is strangely not the case.

One can inspect the document body while in your fiddle, showing that, however the scroll is, the `body` has `scrollTop` of `0` all the time.

So it is not the `body`, that really scrolls, but the `html`. (`scrollTop` on the `html` varies as expected.)

In the updated Fiddle below, I showcased that by including the additional `css` rule `html { overflow: auto; }` which overrides your hidden body overflow.

### scss:

```
html {
  overflow: auto;
}

body{
  &.no-scroll{
    overflow:hidden;
  }
}


.main-box{
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  padding-top: 80px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

.main-header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:10000;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #0ee;
}

.main-content{
  position: relative;
  min-height:1200px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  background-color: #707;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-footer{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ee0;
}

.overlay{
  display: none; //temp
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color: #fff;

  &.visible{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

### html:

```
<div class="main-header">
  header

  <button class="trigger">trigger overlay</button>
</div>

<div class="main-content">content</div>
<div class="main-footer">footer</div>
<div class="overlay">overlay</div>
```

### js:

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(){
    $(document.body).toggleClass('no-scroll');
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjsL2qhq/21/

So, in summary, I guess most browsers do understand the common practice of using hidden overflow on the body, although it makes no real sense. But some manipulations / unorthodox browser interpretations can result in the body not being handled the way you are used to.

Comment: Yes you're right: overflow: auto applied to the html element makes scrollbars appear anyway. And very interesting the article you linked, thank you. To further reserch, I just saw that in some (not too clear to me at the moment) situations, position:relative applied to content elements makes some browsers (namely, safari and explorer) behave differently and let appear scrollbars al the way. This, strangley enough, doesn't apply to our fiddle, but it does apply to the website I'm currently building. So maybe sometimes can be useful to random-play with position:relative... :O

Comment: @Stratboy Yeah, I saw that position thingy in the article as well. I didn't include it, as it did not work for the fiddle. Probably because of the `iframe` fiddle uses. But it still shows, that there are some depths to the issue.